# Not able to post the form

Tags: python, html, sql-server, django, web-applications

So i have a table in ms sql database.the connections is open but the form wont submit.

```
def add(request):
print('start')
if request.method == "POST":
    print('post')

    if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('contact_person') and request.POST.get(
            'address') and request.POST.get('ph_no') and request.POST.get('tele') and request.POST.get(
            'mail') and request.POST.get('is_active') and request.POST.get('last_update'):
        print('get')
        insertstvalues = Company()
        # insertstvalues.company_id = request.POST.get('company_id')
        insertstvalues.name = request.POST.get('name')
        insertstvalues.contact_person = request.POST.get('contact_person')
        insertstvalues.address = request.POST.get('address')
        insertstvalues.ph_no = request.POST.get('ph_no')
        insertstvalues.tele = request.POST.get('tele')
        insertstvalues.mail = request.POST.get('mail')
        insertstvalues.is_active = request.POST.get('is_active')
        # insertstvalues.last_update = request.POST.get('last_date')
        print('values')
        cursor.execute(
            "insert into Company values ('" + insertstvalues.name + "','" + insertstvalues.contact_person + "','" + insertstvalues.address + "','" + insertstvalues.ph_no + "','" + insertstvalues.tele + "','" + insertstvalues.mail + "','" + insertstvalues.is_active + "')")
        print('execute')
        cursor.comit()
        print('record added')
    return render(request, 'addRecord.html')
else:
    print('Rerun')
    return render(request, 'addRecord.html')
```

this is the functions i have in views.py.connections and cursor strings are all working.

here is the html code for the from to take in the values

so when i run the app this is what i see

[cmd terminal after i click the insert button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9RVR.png)

basically as far as i can see is that the program never runs the second if statement.

I want to add data to my table so i am open to any suggestions which might be simpler than what i m trying.
if nothing then how do i make this code work

Comment: not able to add html code.

Comment: You've got yourself a big ol' SQL Injection problem there by embedding user-supplied values into the middle of your insert statement. Obligatory [Little Bobby Tables reference](https://xkcd.com/327/). You should be supplying your form values as pyodbc parameters, making use of [setinputsizes](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) to specify their SQL data types - and sizes in the case of strings (varchar/nvarchar parameters).

Comment: thanks i will look it up

Comment: thanks this helped a lot in undertanding how to work with the sql statements